# flex: cant edit item in Datagrid with override set data method

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, overriding, set, itemeditor

I've a custom itemRenderer for my datagrid. To set the actual data I use the following method:

```
override public function set data(side:Object):void{
   ...
}
```

As soon as I use this function the cell doesn't show up any item Editor anymore. Why is that? When I remove this function the itemEditor is working but with the wrong initialization data...

What's the proper way to handle this?

Thanks,
Markus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have u called 'Super' on that method ?

Comment: Actually my problem is that the function set data gets called with the data of the whole row and afterwards with the data of just the the cell item. So I check now what gets handed over to my side variable and am assigning the values appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you also have an itemEditor that is correctly working or that you set the rendererIsEditor property to true and use the renderer as the editor.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found the problem I had! I wrote it in the comment of Immanuels post! Thanks!